# Is it possible to have a multiline textLabel in a UITableViewHeaderFooterView (without using a custom UILabel)?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to use the built-in `textLabel` in a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` in order display titles in the section headers of a `UITableView`.

These titles have an unknown amount of content and so need to cover multiple lines.

If this was a table cell then `myCell.numberOfLines = 0` would work (along with `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`).  But I can't get anything similar to work with table headers.

I've tried setting `textLabel.numberOfLines = 0` in `viewForHeaderInSection` and/or in `willDisplayHeaderView`.  I've also tried setting it in a custom subclass I've created that the headers are using (set up with `let sectionHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("myIdentifier") as MyTableSectionHeaderSubclass`).  In that subclass I've tried setting `textLabel.numberOfLines = 0` in the `init` function, as well as in `layoutSubviews()`

I've already set the correct height of each header by calculating the amount of space the text string will take up (using `CGSizeMake` in `heightForHeaderInSection`, can provide more info about this if it's of any help).  So, there's enough vertical space for the labels to expand - they're just stuck on one line, with their text cut off and ending with an ellipsis.

I'm trying this approach in order to avoid using a custom UILabel to display the title.  While I can apply multiline that way, this brings other problems such as label position/frame being lost when table rows are added or deleted.

Does anyone know if multi-line text is even possible with a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`'s built-in `textLabel`?  Or is a custom `UILabel` my only option?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do think using a custom `UILabel` is a better approach as you can take control on all attributes.

First of all, a handy function to calculate the UILabel height. (Below is my version for my specific project). Notice that I set the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` which I think is the best way to handle line break, line spacing etc.

```
internal func heightForLabel(attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat, lineSpacing: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing

    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width, height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.textAlignment = .left
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    label.attributedText = attributedString
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.height
}
```

Then in your view controller, pre-calculate the section header heights

```
fileprivate let sectionHeaders = ["Header1", "Loooooooooooooooooooooong Header which occupies two lines"]
fileprivate var sectionHeaderHeights : [CGFloat] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Calculate the label height for each section headers, then plus top and down paddings if there is any. Store the value to `sectionHeaderHeights`
}
```

`UITableViewDelegate` methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return sectionHeaderHeights[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: sectionHeaderHeights[section]-paddings))
    sectionHeader.backgroundColor = .clear

    let sectionTitleLabel = UILabel()
    sectionTitleLabel.text = sectionTitles[section]
    sectionTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "GothamPro", size: 18)
    sectionTitleLabel.textColor = .black
    sectionTitleLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    sectionTitleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: padding, y: sectionHeader.frame.midY, width: sectionTitleLabel.frame.width, height: sectionTitleLabel.frame.height)
    sectionHeader.addSubview(sectionTitleLabel)

    return sectionHeader
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Interface Builder drug the Label above the prototype cell. In the Attribute Inspector set number of lines = 0, Line Break to Word Wrap and enter your text.

Answer (score -3):

Use this one:

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Keep in mind that autosizing works only with:

```
lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" 
numberOfLines="0"
```

One you do that, make sure that inside your cell the contentView constraints are set to top, left, bottom, right related to your textfield.

This way iOS will size the cell to textfield size.

Comment: Please improve a litlle more the answer